# JavaScript Split Array with comma

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have the following array point[] with:

```
11,133,3032,144,412,44,43,44,444,54,22,44,11,163,480,344
```

And I am trying to split with a , every 4.

I would like something like:

```
point[0] = 11,133,3032,144
point[1] = 412,44,43,44
point[2] = 444,54,22,44
point[3] = 11,163,480,344
```

I alreday tried :

`str.split(",", 4)`; but still have the comma at the end and problem of size.

How can I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it an array? Because you're using String.split....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by `splice`-ing the array.

```
var str = "11,133,3032,144,412,44,43,44,444,54,22,44,11,163,480,344";
var arr = str.split(','), result = [];
while(arr.length > 0) {
   result.push(arr.splice(0, 4));
}
```

If you have an array instead of the string, you can just use the last three lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get sub strings from the string, you can also do it with regular expressions.

```
str = "11,133,3032,144,412,44,43,44,444,54,22,44,11";
points = [];
while((match = /([0-9]+,){3}[0-9]+/.exec(str)) != null){
    points.push(match[0]);
    str = str.replace(/([0-9]+,){3}[0-9]+,*/, "");
}
if (str!="")            //if last substring has less than 4 elements
    points.push(str);
```